# Subversion with Git and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, git, svn

Good day Experts,

I need to implement subversion on our WordPress websites.

I have never worked with Subversion before. I have however read-up on it and understand the principles.

We have a Development environment consisting of only one server hosting multiple (about 10) WordPress websites. Then we have a Production Environment that consist of 2 servers, one hosting only the WordPress Files, and the other hosting the WordPress databases. The production Environment is the live environment and we want to completely stray away from making any changes directly on here before it has not been tested via the Development Environment.

I need to implement subversion to basically track the changes on the development environment (obviously with functionality to roll back to a previous version if something goes wrong) and then to make it quick and easy for the team to publish to the Production Environment without having to use FTP – may I add that the sites is about 6GB in size on average. Also as it is the design and development team that is going to work with this it would be nice to have a GUI to work from. (I think they are going to give me grey hair if I need to train them on using console commands.)

Our hosting provider supports SVN and Git. I only have been looking at Git and like I said I understand the principles.

But what I cannot get my head around is how to implement this in our environment. Keeping in mind that this is WordPress Websites and that the Production Environment consist of 2 different servers. Like how do I push the database over to the production environment to a different server than the files?

Sorry if this is maybe stupid questions, but like I said I have never worked with any form of subversion before.

If anyone can send me in the right direction on how I could implement this. It would really be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You **must** (if you want to get good and usable answer) to give more details about 1. "Wordpress development" - is it custom theme design or +modules developments (and does these modules use|change DB in process) or +  customisation or Wordpress core 2. Which communication protocols you can use to communication with DEV|Prod servers 3. Are repository-server(s) are the same|different host than DEV|PROD hosts

Comment: Anyway - SVN is bad choice for your workflow, Git (somehow) better, but give you a lot more headache as tool